# Adding List Items to an Entity Framework Context from a Nested List

Tags: c#, entity-framework, list, reflection, collections

I am trying to insert some records into a database using Entity Framework. What I am struggling with is accessing the properties of the internal lists.

The inner lists have the following structure:

> ```
> public class Innerlist
> {
>     public string item1 { get; set; }
>     public List<string> item2 { get; set; }
>     public List<object> item3 { get; set; }
>     public int item4 {get; set;}
>     etc...
> }
> ```

The above list is then wrapped in another list. My question is how do I  access the properties Item1, Item2, and Item3?

My looping code has the following structure:

```
using(var context = new fooContext())
{
    foreach (var innerList in Outerlist)
    {         
        try
        {
            context.fooEntity.Add(innerList);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n" + ex);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using a foreach loop that looped through the outer list and then another to loop through the inner list. This however generated an error about the class not containing a public definition of 'GetEnumerator'.

The inner foreach loop is structured like this:

```
   foreach (var innerList in outerList)
{
    foreach(var item in innerList)
    {
        try
        {
            context.fooEntity.Add(item);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n" + ex);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

}
```

I am now getting the errors: 'The best overloaded match has some invalid arguments.' And 'Cannot convert from object to InnerList Class.'

**EDIT**

I should add that this is being converted into a list using JSON.net which is taking a JSON string and converting it into a list via the innerList class, which exists as Entity Framework Model class.

Any help would be great. Cheers.

Comment: Post your *looping* code snippet so we can see what you did wrong and how to fix it..

Comment: I meant the inner loop, the one that generated error (your outer loop is working fine isn't it?)... How about simple `foreach(var item in innerList.item2){}`, no?

Comment: @har07 Thanks for your help. I have updated it again.

Comment: The question isn't very clear to me. What is your goal here? If you wanna add `InnerList` class to datacontext then I think you don't need inner loop. If you want to *access properties* of `InnerList` for any other purpose you can do as I suggest in my previous comment (showed an example on how to access `item2` property and loop through it's list member)

Answer (score 0):

Your Innerlist class is not a list. It is a class that contain a list.
Make your Innerlist  object implement [`IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx)